# html2canvas not wrapping text well in Safari

Tags: safari, html2canvas

html2canvas doesn't seem to handle wrapping text correctly for Safari (at least both Catalina and iOS 13.3.1), whereas it works fine under Chrome and Firefox.

```
$('#capture').css('color', 'blue');
html2canvas($('#capture')[0], {}).then(function(canvas) {
    $('#capture').css('color', 'red');
     $('#capture').append(canvas);
   });
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sferrari63/ykbc57u3/20/) that shows the problem.  I've tried specifying larger canvas sizes, scaling, padding and margins, setting scrollX and scrollY to zero, and the rumored letterRendering, but I've had no luck.  Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug with a workaround, or am I just stuck?

(This is probably the same question as [Words are overlapping when rendering the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592511/words-are-overlapping-when-rendering-the-canvas), but I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question and it seems I shouldn't add my info as an answer, since it's not an answer.  How should I really handle this?)

Comment: It looks like this is a Safari bug, fixed in Safari Technology Preview Release 102 (and perhaps back to Release 24).  I've documented this in html2canvas's [github issues](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2177) as well as a potential work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment above, this seems to be a bug in Safari's handling of `getClientBoundingRect` which is fixed in "Safari Technology Preview Release 102 WebKit 15610.1.5.2".

It seems to me that html2canvas's function `testRangeBounds` is meant to detect some other bug in the implementation of `getClientBoundingRect` and if it is buggy, set SUPPORT_RANGE_BOUNDS to be false, which causes `parseTextBounds` to handle text wrapping without relying on `getClientBoundingRect`.  As a work-around, I changed `testRangeBounds` to always return `false`.  This fixed the problem for me in both Catalina Safari and iOS Safari, and it continues to work fine in Chrome.  I suspect the downside is that it's slower, but I'm waiting to hear back on html2canvas's github site.

Comment: I faced the exact same issue now on my project. Chrome seems like the only browser that just works. Both Firefox and Safari have caused me to make a lot of patches. Thanks for the confirmation on the issue. I guess we'll just have to wait for them to fix it.